# Oracle ash report

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, oracle11g, query-optimization

Recently, i have been handed over with an [ash report](https://picasaweb.google.com/chevalier51/March22012?authkey=Gv1sRgCMjIzInF3sXssAE#5715360392626499922) from DBA.

To me this report is like french. I have no idea what it is about and what all is written in this report. Can someone please guide me in reading it and explain me what all steps should i take to make my query stable and less cpu consumer. Moreover, which query is taking more of CPU.
1. Please recommend what actions should i perform.
2. Which query is consuming more of my CPU and what should i do to improve it.

Comment: These are exploratory reports. There isn't going to be a 1-2-3 easy guide to reading them.  Here are some starting points: http://oracledoug.com/serendipity/index.php?/plugin/tag/ASH http://dbakevlar.com/2011/02/for-the-love-of-awr-and-ash/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ASH (Active Session History) report shows what was happening within the database over a range of time.

The `SQL with Top Events` shows, for example, that 31% of time was consumed by the first query.  The SQL ID column can be linked to the `Complete List of SQL Text` used was:

```
select some_giant_list_of_columns
  from VU_PERSON_MINI
 where lower (person_id) = ?
```

That same statement in `Top SQL with Top Row Sources` says it's doing a full table scan (`TABLE ACCESS = FULL`).

I suspect that there's not a function-based index on `LOWER(PERSON_ID)` on VU_PERSON_MINI.  Adding one or fixing the underlying issue (is that a number column?  can you enforce at the application that it's always stored in lower case) should help performance.

Also, the existence of `direct path read` events in that query is somewhat troublesome.  That generally indicates sort activity to disk - or that you're reading LOB data.  Do you mean to be as part of that SQL?

Comment: What is the "31% of time" a percentage of? 31% of time spent in wait events? 31% of the elapsed time in the report? Thanks

Comment: 31% of the overall activity, so it's neither 31% if time in wait, nor is it 31% of the elapsed time in the report.  And that 31% is further subdivided into `direct path reads` and `CPU + Wait for CPU`.